# How to remove the ubuntu name/logo from appearing on top of my desktop background image?

Tags: unity

Is it possible to remove the  Ubuntu name/logo from appearing on top of my desktop background image? I find it pretty intruding and disgraceful. Thanks!
Here is an example of what I mean. The logo is in the bottom left corner.

Desktop with logo:
[image: Desktop with logo]

Zoom on Desktop with logo:
[image: Zoom on Desktop with logo]

Comment: You can simply choose a different wallpaper that doesn't come with the Ubuntu watermark. Or you can use your skills to remove the watermark yourself.

Comment: As @edwinksl indicated, the watermark is not on top of your wallpaper image, it's actually part of the wallpaper image that came with Ubuntu. Switching your desktop wallpaper to an image that doesn't include a watermark will remove the Ubuntu logo completely.

Comment: That's usually a sign of a poor or somewhat incomplete login. Likely due to whatever theme (unmentioned) you're using

Answer (score 0):

Right click your desktop and select "Change Desktop Background" then pick any of the images shown which you prefer (or a color) your desktop image to be changed to.

If this answer solved your problem, please feel free to click the up arrow (where an up, down and number are) next to it on the left.

Comment: If my answer solved your problem (or if it was some else's answer) you should consider marking it as the answer.  It benefits you and that person by increasing the reputation points.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks for the answers!!
The logo was definitely not on the image in the first place.
It seems the problem is that when you find a picture on the net and right click on it and choose 'Set as desktop background' then Ubuntu adds automatically his logo on it.
Because when I followed the instructions given here  meaning I go to Appearance and change it from there, there is no logo! Thats a weird behaviour.
But actually now that I have installed extra software as 'Ubuntu Tweaks' and others the behavior are weird on my desktop.
Thanks again for the help!